# how to execute navigation experimental

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm about to execute navigation_experimental. But, I don't know which launch file I should execute.

A launch folder in eband_local_planner includes gazebo_launch folder, rviz_launch folder and stage_launch folder. The pr2_ompl_planner_base_gazebo.launch in gazebo_launch folder calls 2dnav_stack_fake_loc_planner_prm.launch. The 2dnav_stack_fake_loc_planner_prm.launch calls fake_location.launch and map_server.launch. But, the launch files in groovy seem not to exist.
If you have already executed the package, I'd like you to teach how to execute it.
Could anyone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123116/how-to-execute-navigation-experimental/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Navigation_experimental is not an executable, but rather a stack (metapackage) containing several packages related to navigation.  I suggest that you study the [navigation metapackage](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation), and follow some of the tutorials on that page. The navigation_experimental metapackage has some very specific tools that you normally would not need to use when creating basic setups using ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-02-04**:
Thank you for your reply! Do you mean that navigation_experiment uses navigation stack together? I'm sorry, I'm a beginner for ROS.
For example,
$roscore
$roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
$roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file=/tmp/my_app.yaml
$roslaunch eband_local_planner rviz_move_base.launch
Is this correct?

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-02-04**:
Thanks! I will follow your suggestion.